# Clojure - How merge two/more maps into a single map which have the same value for certain key(s)

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I am learning how to idiomatically destruct data structures in Clojure and currently have the following example data

Data:

```
(def data [
{:category "A", :vertical_name "One", :vertical_id 11}
{:category "B", :vertical_name "Two", :vertical_id 12}
{:category "A", :vertical_name "Three", :vertical_id 13}
{:category "C", :vertical_name "Four", :vertical_id 14}
])
```

I want to merge two/more maps into a single map which belong to the same Category in the data above,

Expected Output:

```
{{:category "A", :vertical [{:vertical_id 11, :vertical_name "One"}{:vertical_id 13,  :vertical_name "Three"}]}
{:category "B", :vertical {:vertical_id 12, :vertical_name "Two"}}
{:category "C", :vertical {:vertical_id 14, :vertical_name "Four"}}}
```

I have tried group-by which gives me

```
{"A" [{:category "A", :vertical_name "One", :vertical_id 11} {:category "A", :vertical_name "Three", :vertical_id 13}],
"B" [{:category "B", :vertical_name "Two", :vertical_id 12}],
"C" [{:category "C", :vertical_name "Four", :vertical_id 14}]}
```

But this has a lot of redundant information, for example `:category "A"` is present in all the maps and the format of the output isn't the way I want it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your expected output isn't a valid map (it has an odd number of elements) maybe you mean it to be a vector?

Comment: @noisesmith - Thanks for pointing out it out. I fixed the quotes. I expect it to be a Map of Maps.

Comment: What you have there is a map from map to map - and it is invalid because a map needs as many keys as values. And a map where the key is one result, and the value is the next one, seems absurd. Maybe you want a set?

Comment: @noisesmith - Yeah! I think I can work with a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user> (->> data
        (group-by :category)
        (map (fn [[k v]]
                 (let [vertical (map #(dissoc % :category) v)
                       vertical (if (< (count vertical) 2)
                                  (first vertical)
                                  (vec vertical))]
                   {:category k
                    :vertical vertical})))
        set)

#{{:category "A", :vertical [{:vertical_name "One", :vertical_id 11} {:vertical_name "Three", :vertical_id 13}]} {:category "B", :vertical {:vertical_name "Two", :vertical_id 12}} {:category "C", :vertical {:vertical_name "Four", :vertical_id 14}}}
```

This is the format you describe, but for most usage it would be worse than the output `group-by` provides. Unlike the `group-by` result, you cannot efficiently look up a given category as the size of the result scales. Further, unlike the result of `group-by`, sometimes the `:vertical` key has a collection, and sometimes a single element, and this is a piece of complexity offloaded onto any other code that accesses this data.

Comment: I get your point. But in my case, once I have it in the specific format, I need to convert that to JSON and return it to the calling device.

Comment: OK - if this is a requirement of someone else's API, then there is no harm in downgrading to the "worse" representation. But if we were designing an API, the default result would be much more usable.